# Dice Loop, With roll again if 6

Tags: c#, loops, dice

new to C# so sorry if this comes off silly.

I have the following code so far regarding my dice:

```
Random DiceRandom = new Random();
int DiceThrow = DiceRandom.Next(1, 7);
Console.WriteLine(DiceThrow);
Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Player 1 rolled a " + DiceThrow);
Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Player 2 rolled a " + DiceThrow);
Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Player 3 rolled a " + DiceThrow);
Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Player 4 rolled a " + DiceThrow);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Now, this creates a number fine and displays it, however it is the same number for every player.

I need a loop that repeats the roll for each individual player, and will roll again if a player rolls a 6.

Comment: come one! Surely you can work out you need to call DiceThrow = DiceRandom.Next(1, 7); each time... If you set a variable once (in any language) what value do you expect it to have?

Comment: @MitchWheat It's not necessarily obvious to people who are new to this. The line `int DiceThrow = DiceRandom.Next(1, 7);` could be taken as, say, an inline definition of a function, if you weren't very familiar with C# and programming in general.

Comment: @Jeff: simple variable assignment is more likely to be assumed by a beginner than a function delegate. Right?

Comment: @MitchWheat Probably *more likely*, but someone more used to mathematics than coding *could* reasonably take the declaration as stating equivalence rather than assignment.

Comment: I can only speak for myself: I have a degree in pure maths. I remember learning to program. It was definitely variable assignment that came first to mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble, as others have pointed out, is that the random number `DiceThrow` is not refreshed each time you use it. You could fix this without using a loop, but don't. You do indeed need a loop, and probably one that looks something like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    DiceThrow = DiceRandom.Next(1,7);
    Console.WriteLine("Player " + i + " rolled a " + DiceThrow);
    Console.ReadLine();
    if(DiceThrow == 6) i--;
}
```

The last line is a little obscure, but is there to provide the "reroll on 6" requirement. Since the loop increments `i` each time, decrementing it will effectively make the loop go around for the same player again.

EDIT: Actually, a more explicit version of this using a while loop instead would be as follows:

```
int i = 1;
while(i <= 4) {
    DiceThrow = DiceRandom.Next(1,7);
    Console.WriteLine("Player " + i + " rolled a " + DiceThrow);
    Console.ReadLine();
    if(DiceThrow != 6) i++;
}
```

Comment: It's generally not good practice to modify the loop variable.  Then again, my answer has an infinite loop =)

Comment: @paddy Yeah, I tend to agree with you, but the other option is either a nested for loop (undesirable also, but perhaps less so I'll admit) or a while loop with a very complicated expression such as `while(player <= 4 && DiceThrow != 6)` or something, and then only update ONE of those variables on each iteration, which sounds horrific to me.

Comment: I opted to use this code Jeff, thanks a lot worked perfectly. 

Now, as it's a game i'm making in which the players keep their scores adding up at the end of each round (i'll say a round is one roll each not including 6's) How would i display the cumulative score at the end of each round, followed by another round?

Comment: @user1890490 I'm glad you found it useful (though I strongly recommend reading both the edit of my answer and paddy's answer, as well as the comments over there). I suggest another question regarding score - questions on Stack Overflow should generally be kept single-topic. Also - please accept the answer you found most useful :)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
for( int player = 1; player <= 4; player++ )
{
    while(1) {
        int DiceThrow = DiceRandom.Next(1, 7);
        Console.WriteLine( "Player " + player + " rolled a " + DiceThrow );
        if( DiceThrow < 6 ) break;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: The OP asked to roll multiple times if a player rolls 6.  That inner loop is one way to achieve it.

Comment: Yeah, a better version of this would be to have `int DiceThrow; while((DiceThrow = DiceRandom.Next(1,7)) != 6){` but even that's pretty clumsy...

Comment: @Jeff Using a while loop in that way also wouldn't enter the loop to display the roll.  That would be very clumsy.  I know people are always going to be in two camps regarding `while(1)` loops, but I encounter them regularly in a professional sense.  In C++, I would use a `do { } while()` construct, but I'm not sure if C# has this.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure of the readlines, etc. But essentially you are referencing the same dice throw each time you print it. What you need to do is generate a new roll (via DiceRandom.Next(1,7)) each time.

```
Random DiceRandom = new Random();

for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    var roll = DiceRandom.Next(1,7);
    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 rolled a " + roll);
}
```